# I add link and get error Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php

I already try my best but not luck.

Here is error message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ','

```
                                <?php
echo '<a style="cursor: pointer"  onclick="javascript: window.location = \'fruit_list.php?do=delete&id=<?php print $fruitdata['id']; ?>/\';">Delete</a>';?>
```

Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the `<?php print ...` section from your command:

```
echo '<a style="cursor: pointer"  onclick="javascript: window.location = \'fruit_list.php?do=delete&id=' . $fruitdata['id'] . '\';">Delete</a>';?>
```

Note that the code could be more readable if you separate it into two lines:

```
$action = "window.location = 'fruit_list.php?do=delete&id={$fruitdata['id']}";
echo '<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="javascript:' . $action . '">Delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo '<a style="cursor: pointer"  onclick="javascript: window.location = \'fruit_list.php?do=delete&id='.$fruitdata['id'].'\';">Delete</a>';?>
```